Adding fixed position on scroll causes flickering element
I have a use case, where I need to make en element positioned fixed whenever you scroll below it.
I can't use position: sticky in this case as the html is not right for it.
I'm using IntersectionObserver to check scroll position, and adding a class with position: fixed.
However, adding position fixed causes the fixed element to flicker/blink like crazy. How can I prevent this?
Js:
const watcher = document.querySelector('.sticky-nav');
const createStickyTOC = () => {
    const toc_config = {
        root: null,
        rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',
        threshold: [.9]
    }

    const toc = (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            // Sticky when scrolling below target
            entry.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('sticky', !entry.isIntersecting && window.scrollY >= entry.boundingClientRect.top);
        })
    }

    if ('IntersectionObserver' in window) {
        const toc_observer = new IntersectionObserver(toc, toc_config);
        toc_observer.observe(watcher);
    }
};

css:
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

See jsFiddle here.

I 've modified your code to the below. Hope it helps.
Edited Javascript:


let elPos = 0
let sticky=false

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var stickyNav = document.querySelector('.sticky-nav');
  var stickyNavTop = stickyNav.offsetTop;

  if (window.pageYOffset > stickyNavTop && !sticky) {
    stickyNav.classList.add('sticky');
    sticky = true
    elPos = stickyNavTop
  } else if(window.pageYOffset < elPos){
    stickyNav.classList.remove('sticky');
    sticky = false
    elPos = 0
  }
});
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: salmon;
}


 div {
   padding: 20px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   margin: 10px;
 }

 body {
   height: 200vh;
 }
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div class="sticky-nav">Sticky Header that when scrolling below it sticks to top</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>
<div>Test Content</div>




That's pretty neat! Thank you. But can it detect when only scrolling below the .sticky-nav? Right now it works when scroling down, but when scrolling up, it doesn't remove the .sticky class before reaching the very top.

I've edited the code above to resolve the issue you mentioned :)
